# My PHP calls are not being made in the right order

Tags: php

**UPDATE**:  Having read all of your advice I tried using !isset() but that does not seem to work either.

If there are 4 calls to the PHP file it seems they must all arrive at the same time so when I perform

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['element_01']) ){$_SESSION['element_01'] = "Something";}
```

it seems 2 or 3 of the calls all find $_SESSION['element_01'] unset!

There must be a solution to this!

============================================================================

I have an application that makes several calls to a php file from the

```
<img src="myfile.php" />
```

Here is an example:

```
<img src="http://myserver.com/demo/?element=1" ></img>
<img src="http://myserver.com/demo/?element=2"></img>
<p>Check out our amazing site for everything we offer</p>
<img src="http://myserver.com/demo/?element=3"></img>
<img src="http://myserver.com/demo/?element=20"></img>
```

When I send the element value to the error_log as each makes their call to my index.php file I get the following in my php_error.log: (NB: They seem to be in random orders)

```
[17-Nov-2013 12:53:54] Element = 2
[17-Nov-2013 12:53:54] Element = 1
[17-Nov-2013 12:53:54] Element = 20
[17-Nov-2013 12:53:54] Element = 3
```

The thing is I rely on element=1 being called first as I an storing a session and using the $_SESSION['element_01'] as a guide for the others but because they seem to reach index.php in random orders this is causing PHP errors such as:

```
PHP Notice: Undefined offset:  -1 in http://myserver.com/demo/index.php on line 133
```

Many users can be arriving at the example web page at the same time, just in case that makes any difference.

So to my question:

1. Is there a way around this or is there a way to ensure they are called in the right order?  Something I am doing wrong maybe?.

Thank you.

Comment: It is for browsers to decide which image on a page to fetch first. You can however look at JavaScript Images Prefetching and prefetch that very image first.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I did wonder if browsers did their own thing on this!

Comment: If caching is properly set up the browser might not ask for the images at all on a second visit. Don't rely on what the browser might do: set up your session based on what the server is being asked for. i.e. your PHP script.

Comment: Oddly it does all work on a second refresh because by that time all of the session variables are set.  What did you mean by, "set up your session based on what the server is being asked for. i.e. your PHP script?" and thank you.

Comment: You _should_ be caching static resources like images for days or weeks, but sessions should expire quickly for security reasons. A second visit might occur after the session has expired, but before the cache does. (e.g. the following day). You can rely on the PHP script being called first, so set up your session there.

Comment: I have tried using isset() but that does not seem to work either.  If there are 4 calls to the PHP file it seems they must all arrive at the same time so when I perform if(!isset($_SESSION['element_01']) ){}, it seems 2 or 3 of them find $_SESSION['element_01'] unset! :-(

Answer (score 1):

This order depends on factors you can't control (what the user's browser ask first and the traffic of the request to your server, for example). You can't rely on this order for any procedure.

You must perform this procedure elsewhere, before to print the pictures. Or check if that variable is defined (take a look on [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) language contruct) before use it and, if not, create it.

Comment: Thank you.  I will need to rethink this! AND I was just looking at the isset() when you sent your next reply! :-)

Comment: [pedantic] from the `isset` documentation: _"this is a language construct and not a function"_. An important distinction IMO[/pedantic]. @Andy: read the help section: you are asked _not_ to leave _"thank you"_ comments, but instead mark the answer that helped you the most as accepted.

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem, you're right, this is important! I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a specific way to get the images (or any other kind of resource) loaded in a specific order. I believe you should load those images with AJAX or any other way rather trusting the browser into this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I would use AJAX (and do for other things) but this application allows users to put these calls on their own web pages so I cannot insist on AJAX!